# Merging two branches, one with Postgres and another with SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, postgresql, sqlite

Like the title says, I am building a rails app and switching over from SQLite3 to Postgres.  I believe i have successfully made the switch over as all my queries are working successfully, but it is on a branch.

Can I do a standard `git merge [branch] master` or should I do something else?

Im worried that the merge will have a ton of conflicts and just leave me with an app somewhere in the middle of SQLite and psql. I have been working hard on this and dont want to screw it up.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options for bringing the Postgres branch into `master` are basically merging and rebasing.  In either case, you might get merge conflicts in the process, because you changed the queries around and Git might not be able to figure out how to resolve automatically.

Assuming that no other changes have been made to the original queries in `master` from the point when you branched off, you should be able to just retain your Postgres queries as being the authoritative version without paying too much attention to the conflicts.

If you suspect that someone else in your team might have modified some `.sql` files, then you can switch to the `master` branch and look at a diff between the commit in `master` where you branched off, and the `HEAD`, e.g.

```
git diff <SHA-1 from branching> HEAD -- someFile.sql
```

If the diff shows any changes in the file `someFile.sql`, then the queries may have changed, and you should pay special attention when you merge/rebase your feature branch with `master`.